# Need to sum values of entire row, then divide by the count of blank cells in same row

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to create a cheat sheet to get the glass size of a railing system. Row 100 has the post dimensions, gap dimensions, (glass size dimensions needed) and any other hardware dimensions needed as well.I figured if i enter the overall length of a railing system (240") on cell A1, i could plot all the post & hardware width dimensions in row 100, leave a blank cell for the glass size, and i could eventually get the number of blank cells (number of glass panels) to divide A1 by the number of blank cells (number of glass panels). Once i get that answer, i would input the formula in the blank cells (glass panel width dimension). When i do that, i get a circular reference error. :( How can i achieve calculating the amount of glass panels i could put into a specific length (A1) and calculate the glass panel width?

I currently have =sum((A1)-sum(100:100))/Countif(100:100,""). This formula brings up a circular reference error, since i am placing it inside row 100 various times.

For reference, A1 will vary, depending on what length i put in (example would be 60"). A100 has a value of 2" for the first post dimension, B100 has 1" for a gap, C100 will have a formula to calculate glass width size, D100 has 1" for a gap, and E100 will have 2" for the last post dimension. So, the formula would have to calculate (60)-2-1-"empty cell"-1-2=54, then 54/1=1 (1 is the number of empty cells in row 100). So , the number to populate in the "empty cell" (C100) is 54". But if A1 has a value of 100", A100:E100 will transpose to the right to allow for more glass panels to exist (glass panels cannot be more than 60")

Comment: Is row 100 manually entered or formulas based on the value in A1? Maybe a screenshot would help.

Comment: Row100 is based on formulas. A1 has the total length. A100 calculates the width of an end post (end posts have different dimensions than regular posts). B100 Calculates a 1" gap. C100 will eventually calculate the glass width (the reason for this thread). D100 calculates another 1" gap. E100 will either calculate an end post if A1<= 60, or a regular post if A1>60. If A1>60, then F100 will calculate a 1" gap, G100 will eventually calculate another glass width, & so on. The point of row100 is to figure out how many glass panels are needed and what the exact dimension of each glass panels are.

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, you can't use formulas to change their own inputs. A spreadsheet isn't like an imperative programming language which gets executed in a well defined sequence.

So instead of changing the cells while you're using them, put the formulas somewhere else. Maybe on row 101 or in another sheet. Then the information encoded in the blank cells remains and can be used by the formulas whenever they get re-evaluated.

Or perhaps instead of making blank cells, can you calculate their values at the same time as the rest of row 100? **EDIT:** The formula for C100, G100, etc., instead of creating blanks, could directly fill in the glass widths according to A1. Such as `= if(A1 > ..., A1 / 60 -..., "")`. The "..."s in that formula probably depend on the number of panels which you can calculate from A1, but since that calculation is probably complicated and you'd reuse it a lot, it would be tidier to store the number of panels in a different cell so you can refer to it in these formulas.

The general issue is that, when using formulas, you can't store intermediate results in the same cells as final results because that would make it impossible for the formula to still be correct after it's evaluated and changed its own input. Intermediate results have to either go in a different cell or be avoided by writing one big formula that has no intermediate results.

Comment: The idea of using the entire row is to expand the posts, gaps and glass panels if the value in A1 exceeds 60", and have a visual of what it's going to look like. I tried putting a formula to calculate the glass size in cell B2 [ =MROUND(SUM(SUM(100:100)),0.0625)*MROUND(SUMPRODUCT((LEN(101:101)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(101:101,"Glass","")))/LEN("Glass")),0.0625) ] and tried [ =B2 ] in cell C100. But that also brings up a circular reference error. Is there any other way to figure this out? I'm open to VBA as well.

Comment: Yes, you could use VBA read from then write to some cells. I can't go into much detail on that myself though. Maybe make a new question specific to reading and writing a cell in VBA. However, you're encoding information in blank cell count which is complicating things. It might be a lot simpler to put that data into cells specially made for it, like "number of panels". Then you won't have to read the entire row which is leading to the circular references.